# Queries on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document which look like this,

```
{
    "_index": "w3-commsvc",
    "_type": "message",
    "_id": "h98yv662",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "messageId": "h98yv662",
        "campaignName": "src_checkoutAbandon",
        "campaignId": "cId_w3_website",
        "states": [
            {
                "Delivered": 790709218
            },
            {
                "open": 1288775055
            },
            {
                "click": 319518555
            },
            {
                "DEFERRED": 2137606534
            }
        ],
        "clientName": "w3_website",
        "templateId": "test",
        "opens": [
            {
                "url": "www.something.com",
                "id": "t26jj783",
                "userAgent": {
                    "browser": {
                        "family": "IE",
                        "version": "11.0",
                        "major": "11",
                        "minor": "0",
                        "patch": null
                    },
                    "os": {
                        "family": "Windows_XP",
                        "version": null,
                        "versionPopularName": null,
                        "major": null,
                        "minor": null,
                        "patch": null,
                        "patchMinor": null
                    },
                    "device": {
                        "family": "Other",
                        "type": "Computer"
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": "1372366437"
            },
            {
                "url": "www.something.com",
                "id": "t98ef285",
                "userAgent": {
                    "browser": {
                        "family": "IE",
                        "version": "11.0",
                        "major": "11",
                        "minor": "0",
                        "patch": null
                    },
                    "os": {
                        "family": "Windows_XP",
                        "version": null,
                        "versionPopularName": null,
                        "major": null,
                        "minor": null,
                        "patch": null,
                        "patchMinor": null
                    },
                    "device": {
                        "family": "Other",
                        "type": "Computer"
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": "717918284"
            }
        ],
        "clicks": [
            {
                "url": "www.something.com",
                "id": " j60te707",
                "userAgent": {
                    "browser": {
                        "family": "IE",
                        "version": "11.0",
                        "major": "11",
                        "minor": "0",
                        "patch": null
                    },
                    "os": {
                        "family": "Windows_XP",
                        "version": null,
                        "versionPopularName": null,
                        "major": null,
                        "minor": null,
                        "patch": null,
                        "patchMinor": null
                    },
                    "device": {
                        "family": "Other",
                        "type": "Computer"
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": "1293320728"
            },
            {
                "url": "www.something.com",
                "id": " c63bc623",
                "userAgent": {
                    "browser": {
                        "family": "IE",
                        "version": "11.0",
                        "major": "11",
                        "minor": "0",
                        "patch": null
                    },
                    "os": {
                        "family": "Windows_XP",
                        "version": null,
                        "versionPopularName": null,
                        "major": null,
                        "minor": null,
                        "patch": null,
                        "patchMinor": null
                    },
                    "device": {
                        "family": "Other",
                        "type": "Computer"
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": "624917313"
            },
            {
                "url": "www.something.com",
                "id": " f10qm",
                "userAgent": {
                    "browser": {
                        "family": "Firefox",
                        "version": "11.0",
                        "major": "11",
                        "minor": "0",
                        "patch": null
                    },
                    "os": {
                        "family": "Windows_XP",
                        "version": null,
                        "versionPopularName": null,
                        "major": null,
                        "minor": null,
                        "patch": null,
                        "patchMinor": null
                    },
                    "device": {
                        "family": "Other",
                        "type": "Computer"
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": "334734507"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now using the above documents i need the following answer for the following queries,

1 - I need the terms count of each state for a certain clientName.
2 - Total sum of length of each opens array in the document.
3 - Open and click stats for each browsers.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: For 1st I still have no idea..

Comment: For 1st one you can do double term aggregation. First use term aggregation to group documents by customerName and then use nested term aggregation using field states with nested fields. It will group all of documents which have the same value of for example state.Delivered.

Comment: the following query:
{  
    "aggs" : {  
         "StatesTermCount" : {  
               "terms" : {  
                     "field" : "states"  
               }  
        }  
}  
  
gives following result:
"aggregations":  
{  
"value":  {  
"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}}}